# Autostart application not working when done manually/programmatically

Tags: python, autostart

I am currently writing a background changer for Ubuntu that runs upon login. After a lot of head-desking, I finally decided an autostart application was the way to do it.

However, autostart applications that I don't make in the Startup Applications GUI will not work *even if they are copy-pasted*. (They will not work when made either programmatically or copy-pasted manually, I mean to say.) I've tried very hard to replicate the file output of the GUI, but no matter what I try, it just will not work. They will not work when saved as python.desktop. They will not work when saved in `desktop_changer.desktop`. However, the manually and programmatically inserted files will *appear* in the GUI, and if I make a slight adjustment in the GUI (such as changing the name or adding a space) they will suddenly work! Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Python:

```
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.config/autostart/python.desktop"), "w") as file:
    command = "[Desktop Entry] \nType=Application \nExec=python {}/main.py {} {}\nName=Desktop Changer\n".format(path, arg, minutes)
    file.write(command)
```

Main method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    time.sleep(10)
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))


    while True:

        #Set pic, set timer, run continously
        for img in os.listdir('pics/'):
            print(os.path.abspath('pics/' + img))
            set_gnome_wallpaper(os.path.abspath('pics/' + img))
            time.sleep(10)
```

And `set_gnome_wallpaper()`:

```
def set_gnome_wallpaper(file_path):
    command = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'zoom' && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://'%s'" % file_path
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

File output (`~/.config/autostart/python.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Type=Application 
Exec=python /home/chessie/program/python/desktop_changer/main.py SPE 60.0
Name=Desktop Changer
```

When I do it via GUI and delete the extraneous parts (~/.config/autostart/python.desktop):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=python /home/chessie/program/python/desktop_changer/main.py SPE 60.0
Name=Desktop Changer
```

I cannot imagine what could be causing the disparity. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

Comment: @Xaqron Thanks, but that won't seem to do anything when applied to the manually created or pythonically created .desktop files.

Comment: +1 for Pythonically. I would first test my autostart and then the application. Use another app to test autostart and if it works then your app has problem.

Comment: Hi user72 and so on, I am pretty sure you have a timing issue. The desktop needs to be fully loaded. Try: `Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python /home/chessie/program/python/desktop_changer/main.py SPE 60.0"`. Possibly you need to play a little with the timing. I cannot be sure though without knowing the script exactly. If it works, I will make it an answer though. Please mention.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you so much, but that didn't appear to fix the problem, either. I'll go ahead and post the main method of my python (most of it is currently commented out as I focus on this problem) but I actually put a sleep timer in the beginning of the main method as well.

Comment: A few questions: i) I assume you tested the script on a running system? ii) I am curious to the function `set_gnome_wallpaper()`

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yep, the script works when I call it directly (python /home/chessie/program/python/desktop_changer/main.py SPE 60.0). It changes the background just beautifully when I call it directly, as it does when I set it up using the Startup Applications GUI interface. It just doesn't run when I create a .desktop file manually for some reason. Even when I run 'ps -x | grep main.py' after login, it is not running. I'll add the set_gnome_wallpaper() for you though.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a concrete issue (e. g. changing desktop wallpapers on log-in or periodically) or are you trying so solve a programming issue? The former is on topic here and will likely result in this question being closed as a duplicate of a similar question; the latter is off topic here and the question will likely be closed for that reason.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'm actually assuming I misunderstood how the standard Ubuntu Startup Application software works, in which case I need someone with a deep understanding of how Ubuntu software works specifically. Or maybe even I stumbled on a new bug in Ubuntu 16.04. I could not find anyone with the same problem or one similar enough that I could make an inference to solve this (_believe me_, I've looked.) I'm guessing my problem needs more of an Ubuntu-expert than a Python-expert. I apologize if I'm in the wrong place, though.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: are you looking to solve a practical problem or a programming problem, i. e. does the solution need to be based on your previous source code or can it be an entirely different approach or tool? There are multiple questions on how to change Unity desktop wallpapers automatically/periodically/programmatically.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think your question unintentionally assumes a false dichotomy. I am looking for a way to use _this_ piece of software, a feature of which is that it can be used programmatically. (Though I wouldn't say no to another tool that I could use programmatically!) I provided my Python code upon request, but the code might not _be_ the problem, considering it also doesn't work when I just copy-paste. My guess is that I'm misunderstanding the software somehow. You are welcome to flag a mod and let them decide if you have doubts, though--I don't want to take up more of your time.